# Use different mysql table for users

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, mysql, user, sql

I need to integrate a `users` table instead of the default Joomla `_user` table.

The table `pref_users` has simple id/user/email/password fields (not hashed). Is there anyway I can make Joomla use it instead of the default table for users?

Comment: Doing that will involve a large amount of core changes, not to mention you will get a load of errors due to a format mismatch. Also, why would you **password** values **not** be hashed? I don't see why you can't simply put all the data from you table into the default `#__users` table and then run a simple PHP script to hash each password. Joomla is  CMS, therefore you're supposed to use what's built into it. Don't start changing the way it works. If you need anything extra, then built **on top** of what is already provided

Comment: Alright that makes sense. How would I run a script to hash all my passwords? I was Googling it and it says Joomla uses md5 salt and hash but from there i'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Well you're using Joomla 3.x which uses `bcrypt`. Run a database query to get all the passwords, then in a `foreach` loop, use the bcrypt function.

Answer (score 1):

You can check user helper file in Joomla! library `{site_root}/libraries/user/helper.php`

You will find all related functions over there. To convert pain text to hash password there is a function called `getCryptedPassword`. This function accepts several arguments. In most cases default arguments works perfectly, but You can use them as per your need.

With default argument:

```
$passwordhash = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword('plain_text_password');
```

Comment: `getCryptedPassword` by default uses `md5_hex`, so seeing as this is Joomla 3.x, should the OP not be used `JUserHelper::hashPassword('plan_text')` ?

Comment: But as he is going to create his own user table and user functionality (as changing table will surely need to change whole user logic to...). He can use it.

Comment: If it is only matter of converting plain text to what Joomla is using. Then you are correct, we have to pass `crypt-blowfish` in argument.